# rowsum of last column of dataframe

Tags: r

I have a function below to calculate summary,i want to calculate the sum of last row (last row can have many columns, also can have "NA". do we have any solution for this..????

```
dataa<-data.frame(
  aa = c("q","r","y","v","g","y","d","s","n","k","y","d","s","t","n","u","l","h","x","c","q","r","y","v","g","y","d","s","n","k","y","d","s","t","n","u","l","h","x","c"),
col1=c(1,2,3,2,1,2,3,4,4,4,5,3,4,2,1,2,5,3,2,1,2,4,2,1,3,2,1,2,3,1,2,2,4,4,4,1,2,5,3,5),
col2=c(2,1,1,7,4,1,2,7,5,7,2,6,2,2,6,3,4,3,2,5,7,5,6,4,4,6,5,6,4,1,7,3,2,7,7,2,3,7,2,4)
)



  df <- database %>% select(!!var1,!!var2)
  tab1 <- expss::cro_cpct(df[[1]],df[[2]])
  
Error in FUN(X[[i]], ...) : 
  only defined on a data frame with all numeric variables
```

Comment: Could you please create a more **minimal** example?

Comment: Why don't you simply use `sum(tab1[nrow(tab1), -1]`?

Comment: getting error  with sum(tab1[nrow(tab1), -1]
Error in FUN(X[[i]], ...) : 
  only defined on a data frame with all numeric variables

Comment: I tried the solution suggested by @nico : `sum(tab1[nrow(tab1), -1])`, (nico had missed the right parenthesis) after running exactly the code you provided in your question, @sanuali0123. It works, so either 1) close the question, or 2) ask nico to write the suggestion as an answer so you can mark it as an accepted solution. If your error persists, you're doing something different than what you've described in your question.

Comment: yes it worked for me too, lets wait for @nico suggestions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your first column contains the string `#Total cases`, `sum` will throw an error. Excluding the first column will work. Also, adding `na.rm=TRUE` will ignore NAs

```
 sum(tab1[nrow(tab1),-1], na.rm = T)
```